# Is there a good way to create a ring topology using socket?

Tags: java, sockets, unix, networking

When I'm building some interesting things I got a problem. I need to connect several hosts (not many, like 10) in a *ring* topology, using socket, of course.

The tricky thing here I think is the roles in a socket connection, i.e. server & client. The condition where I'm concerning requires a *symmetric* way to connect with each other(every host is equivalent). However, socket can only provide an *asymmetric* way in which there must be a server and a client.

Actually I've come up with a solution: for each host, the socket connected to its left neighbor acts as a server, while the socket connected to the right on acts as a client. This works and is scalable. But it's not so straightforward anyway.

Could anyone comes up with better solutions or just tells me this one is just the best? :)
Thanks for your brilliant insight.

Comment: UDP is connectionless, and thus can be used for a more symmetrical topology than TCP.

Comment: It doesn't matter wheter you are using UDP or TCP. You still need to have something waiting for incomming data (server) and something to send the data (client).

Comment: I think your question is to general. What is the usage and much more important what requirements do you have to set up the connections between the servers. Do you need some kind of self discovery? Do you need some kind of self healing if a serverdies? Or are you just fine with a hardcoded list of server manually distributed to your servers?

Comment: @BetaRide Actually the only requirement is connectivity. Amount of hosts can be fixed, and there is no need to self-healing. I just want to make them able to send message freely in the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could relax your design in one way. Basically, for each of the two neighbor pairs, float a TCP listener at both neighbors and then let them wait/sleep for a random time. Whoever wakes up first, initiates the connection (using connect()). This way, you dont have to worry about right peer connecting to the left peer.

Comment: Good idea! I gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most robust is, that each node has client and server to both directions. If there is no connection, then it tries to connect both ways.

If a situation arises where there is suddenly two connections between some two hosts, then IP address of each node can be used to determine which connection is closed. For example, the host with larger IP closes it's client connection, while the host with smaller IP closes it's server connection (doesn't matter how you define "smaller" and "larger" value for IP as long as it's same for both), and the other connection remains alive.